# sql code for week should start on monday end on sunday

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Business starts from Monday and ends on Sunday as a complete week. So I need to group by week in SSRS. How can I do this?

I am attaching the screenshot of my requirement.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the table definition of your source data.

Comment: Right now am using DATE PART(wk,date-field) to group by week as parent group.Inside this date column is again column grouped...as u see in screen shot shared. so am getting first day as SUNDAY instead of Monday....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `SET DATEFIRST 1;`

`DATEFIRST` will set the first day of the week according to value given. 1 is for `Monday`, 2 `TUESDAY` and so on.

It will always have a fixed value for days. Like 1 will always be Monday and 7 will always be Sunday.

`SELECT @@DATEFIRST` will give the Week start day. By default it will be 7 i.e. Sunday. So if you run `SET DATEFIRST 1` then `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` will return 1.

You may have to put `SET DATEFIRST 1` inside Stored Procedure along with your query.

Comment: OK. then Monday will be day 1...what is query for displaying what number assigned for days ?. like Monday 1 ,Tuesday 2 etc... It will be better if you elaborate the query and solution.

Comment: Thank you Semicolon for your time and information...I got your answer and now it is perfectly working .

Comment: You're Welcome @SiddarthaGr